# substr without breaking inline style

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I have this paragraph. I want to break this paragraph into further n paragraphs without breaking inline style given that is given through span tag to the text.**

`<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; text-decoration: underline;">`Then they introduced the princess of the fairies, her name was Patty. Her dad, the king of the fairies, called her Patty the Pooh. She was very pretty, she had short Blonde hair with a crown made out of gold and an outfit fit for a princess. The princess said she had good news, one of the fairies was going to have a baby fairy. Everyone congratulated her. Then she went on, we found out a few weeks ago but we didn’t want to jinx it. Everyone congratulated her again and went to bed. The next morning she had the baby. She decided to name her Julia. When she turned one and was able to walk Jesse and Mary Sue were still there. It was Saturday when Jesse and Mary Sue were about to leave and then they heard a familiar voice and decided to stay for another night.Then they introduced the princess of the fairies, her name was Patty. Her dad, the king of the fairies, called her Patty the Pooh. She was very pretty, she had short Blonde hair with a crown made out of gold and an outfit fit for a princess. The princess said she had good news, one of the fairies was going to have a baby fairy. Everyone congratulated her. Then she went on, we found out a few weeks ago but we didn’t want to jinx it. Everyon`<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">e congratulated her again and went to bed. The next morning she had the baby. She decided to name her Julia. When she turned one and was able to walk Jesse and Mary Sue were still there. It was S</span>`aturday when Jesse and Mary Sue were about to leave and then they heard a familiar voice and decided to stay for another night.Then they introduced the princess of the fairies, her name was Patty. Her dad, the king of the fairies, called her Patty the Pooh. She was very pretty, she had short Blonde hair with a crown made out of gold and an outfit fit for a princess. The princess said she had good news, one of the fairies was going to have a baby fairy. Everyone congratulated her. Then she went on, we found out a few weeks ago but we didn’t want to jinx it. Everyone congratulated her again and went to bed. The next morning she had the baby. She decided to name her Julia. When she turned one and was able to walk Jesse and Mary Sue were still there. It was Saturday when Jesse and Mary Sue were about to leave and then they heard a familiar voice and decided to stay for another night.Then they introduced the princess of the fairies, her name was Patty. Her dad, the king of the fairies, called her Patty the Pooh. She was very pretty, she had short Blonde hair with a crown made out of gold and an outfit fit for a princess. The princess said she had good news, one of the fairies was going to have a baby fairy. Everyone congratulated her. Then she went on, we found out a few weeks ago but we didn’t want to jinx it. Everyone congratulated her again and went to bed. The next morning she had the baby. She decided to name her Julia. When she turned one and was able to walk Jesse and Mary Sue were still there. It was Saturday when Jesse and Mary Sue were about to leave and then they heard a familiar voice and decided to stay for another night.Then they introduced

This is the function that i have been trying to work with but its not working as i expected. It breaks the inline style

```
      function htmlSubstring(s, n) {
          var m, r = /<([^>\s]*)[^>]*>/g,
              stack = [],
              lasti = 0,
              result = '';

          //for each tag, while we don't have enough characters
          while ((m = r.exec(s)) && n) {
              //get the text substring between the last tag and this one
              var temp = s.substring(lasti, m.index).substr(0, n);
              //append to the result and count the number of characters added
              result += temp;
              n -= temp.length;
              lasti = r.lastIndex;

              if (n) {
                  result += m[0];
                  if (m[1].indexOf('/') === 0) {
                      //if this is a closing tag, than pop the stack (does not account for bad html)
                      stack.pop();
                  } else if (m[1].lastIndexOf('/') !== m[1].length - 1) {
                      //if this is not a self closing tag than push it in the stack
                      stack.push(m[1]);
                  }
              }
          }

          //add the remainder of the string, if needed (there are no more tags in here)
          result += s.substr(lasti, n);

          //fix the unclosed tags
          while (stack.length) {
              result += '</' + stack.pop() + '>';
          }

          return result;
      }
```

**Please help me.**

Comment: wooooooooow outline your question, this is bad for the eyes!

Comment: @VDesign is it ok now?

Comment: please edit it properly its unreadable

Comment: Rather than posting a wall of text, it would be better if you could post relevant code that you attempted and what isn't working.

Comment: What do you consider a paragraph?

Comment: use `<pre> tag` it will work

Comment: This questions is far too vague without guidelines of expectations. Also should post code attempts that have been made to solve it. People aren't here just to do your work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really dont know what exactly you want to achieve.

But [that script](http://jsfiddle.net/xtvpbp8o/7/) will allow you to split the text into n paragraphs (your < span/>s still work):

```
var cntParagraphs = 3,
    $el = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0],
    text = $el.innerHTML,
    textLength = text.length,
    brkPnt = Math.round(textLength / cntParagraphs),
    brkPntMatch,
    brkPntMatch2,
    regExp,
    regExp2,
    i;

for(i=1; i<cntParagraphs; i++) {
    regExp = new RegExp('^(.{' + i * brkPnt +'}[^\.]*\\.)(.*)$');
    brkPntMatch = text.match(regExp);
    if(brkPntMatch) {
        regExp2 = new RegExp('(<[^\/].{1,80}>)[^<\/]*$');
        brkPntMatch2 = brkPntMatch[1].match(regExp2);
        if(brkPntMatch2) {
            text = brkPntMatch[1] + '</p><p>' + brkPntMatch2[1] + brkPntMatch[2];
        }
        else {
            text = brkPntMatch[1] + '</p><p>' + brkPntMatch[2];
        }
    }
}

text = '<p>' + text + '</p>';
$el.innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: I don't want to user <br> tag to separate text. Actually instead of <br> i want to enclose each section into <p> tag.

Comment: Actually i am not that good with regular expression thats why i asked the question here.

Comment: Now according to your new code the styling is being destroyed in first paragraph. see this example http://jsfiddle.net/xtvpbp8o/2/

Comment: Sure - cause of the <p> the inline <style> is ended. Thats why i used the <br>s :) Alternatively you could do something like: http://jsfiddle.net/xtvpbp8o/5/